# Capture ENTER KeyEvent and Do a Click instead

Tags: java, awt, capture, keylistener, keyevent

I have added ENTER Key to the default FocusTraversalKeys as such...

```
private void focus() {
    Set forwardKeys = getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
    Set newForwardKeys = new java.util.HashSet(forwardKeys);
    newForwardKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0));
    setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, newForwardKeys);
}
```

I have a Product Information form that I am going through using the focus but when it comes to a save button I would like to **CLICK the button** instead of the focus going to the next component.

I have added a KeyPressed and KeyReleased listener to the button and then tried this...

```
private void saveButtonKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        evt.consume();
        saveButton.doClick();
    }
}
```

This same method works on my Text Area BUT the code doesn't do the CLICK instead puts the focus on next component which is also a button.

Please suggest something that would help me achieve the required result. Find below the Image of the form used.

http://tinypic.com/r/33acqy9/5

Comment: You could set the focus transferal keys for the button to be default (ie `TAB`), meaning that the `ENTER` key will perform as default...

Comment: @MadProgrammer That is what I have done already, set Focus Traversal Key of everything in that Frame to include ENTER Key. I want to do "Space bar" effect when it comes to the Button and not transfer Focus to next component.

Comment: You can set the focus transfer keys for an individual component as well. Have a look at the [answer by kleo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the ENTER Key from the SET i defined when button gains Focus and thus it works with the KeyReleased Method now.

```
private void saveButtonFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                       
    newForwardKeys.remove(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0));  
    setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, newForwardKeys);
}
```

Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Check out [Enter Key and Button](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/enter-key-and-button/) for some solutions, one using key bindings and the other using a different approach.

Comment: Tried using the DefaultButtonListener class in the link you gave but it didn't help.